# References for a unnamed theorem of complex analysis used within numerical analysis proof.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, numerical-linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

The theorem I was trying to understand is taken in "Introduction to Numerical Analysis, Stoer,Bulirsch", and it's the following :

$\textbf{Theorem :}$ Let $\lambda$ be a simple zero of the characteristic polynomial of the  $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and $x, y^{H}$ corresponding right and left eigenvectors of $A$ respectively and let $C$ be an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix. Then there exists a function $\lambda(\epsilon)$ which is analytic for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, $\vert \epsilon \vert < \epsilon_{0}, \epsilon_{0} > 0$ such that $\lambda(0) = \lambda, \lambda'(0) = \frac{y^{H}C x}{y^{H}x}$ and $\lambda(\epsilon)$ is a simple zero of the characteristic polynomial of $A + \epsilon C$. One has, in first approximation, $\lambda(\epsilon) = \lambda + \epsilon \frac{y^{H}C x}{y^{H}x}$ (excluding terms of order greater of equal $\epsilon^{2}$)

At a certain point the proof justify the characterization of a simple zero using an integral formula "according to another theorem in complex analysis". Since this theorem doesn't belong to my references I was hoping to find some here.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: this appears to be the integral form of the Winding Number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2i \pi}\int_{\gamma}z\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$$

is the **sum of zeros of $f$ inside the closed loop $\gamma$** (proof with the residue formula:see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2523592) by taking $g(z):=f$). If this loop is small enough as to enclose only a (simple) root, you get the representation given in the text.

Besides, for the other part of your question, there is a natural connection between the so-called Rayleigh quotients $X^TCX/X^TX$ and eigenvalues as you can see in [this text](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2019/notes/Class6.pdf).

See as well this [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651150).

Comment: I don't get where the factor "z" comes from, could you please give me some details ?

Comment: There is no true explanation : if it wasn't there, the integral of f'(z)/f(z) alone would give the number of zeros inside the loop, instead of the root inside the loop; if instead of $z$, you had $z^2$ you would get the sum of the squares of the roots inside the loop, etc...

Comment: I don't neither where it comes from nor why I get the root instead of the number

Comment: Do you agree that the result comes from the application of the **residue theorem** to the simple pole of $zf '(z)/f(z)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is representation is obtained in the proof of the inverse function theorem in complex analysis. The background you need to have is residue theory of complex analysis. I found a reference online for you.
[http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~fjmliou/rsurface/inverseholo.pdf](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/%7Efjmliou/rsurface/inverseholo.pdf)

Comment: As already said, I don't get where the factor "z" comes from, could you please give me some details ?